# Callback when a modal form closes

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

How can I call a method after I close a modal form in ionic2 (`v 2.1.7`) ? Following is my workflow

- user loads a page (page A)
- then click on a button to open a modal form (page B)
- add some details (this will update a service)
- close the modal form (page B)
- Now I want to add a callback to page A and read the new value from
  the service

This is what I've done

```
#page A
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(NewListPage);
modal.present();
getValueFromService() 

#page B
updateService()
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
```

Currently what happens is, once the program hits `modal.present();`, its not waiting for the `Page B` to close before its going to `getValueFromService()`, due to this, the newly updated value cannot be read once I close the modal form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onDidDismiss` ([doc](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/components/modal/ModalController/#advanced)) like this:

```
 // Page A
 presentModal() {
   let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(NewListPage);

   modal.onDidDismiss(() => {
     // This is going to be executed when the modal is closed, so
     // you can read the value from the service here
     getValueFromService();
   });

   modal.present();
 }
```

And then like you said

```
// Page B
updateService();
this.viewCtrl.dismiss();
```

Please also notice that you can send data between the `Page A` and the `Page B`, so maybe you can even avoid using a service (if you're doing it just for sending the data back and forth) and just send the data like this:

```
 // Page A
 presentModal() {
   let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(NewListPage);

   modal.onDidDismiss(dataFromModal => {
     // You can use the data here
     console.log(dataFromModal.foo);
   });

   modal.present();
 }
```

And in page B

```
// Page B
// Instead of calling the service, you can send the data to the caller
let data = { 'foo': 'bar' };
this.viewCtrl.dismiss(data);
```

Comment: Glad to hear that :)